# Post picture to my Facebook page without link

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I am writing a script to automatically retrieve a *.png* file from a directory and post it to my Facebook page with a bunch of hashtags as its message.function

```
publish($filename, $card_type, $message){
    $filename = "http://www.mywebsite.com/sandboxassets/img/burrocards/" . $card_type . "/" . $filename;
    echo 'publish this file: ' . $filename;
    // retrieve fb credentials
    $config_vals = parse_ini_file("../../../nicethings.ini");
    $appid = $config_vals['fbappid'];
    $token = $config_vals['fbtoken'];
    $secret = $config_vals['fbsecret'];
    // initialize Facebook class using your own Facebook App credentials
    $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
      'app_id' => $appid,
      'app_secret' => $secret,
      'default_graph_version' => 'v2.8',
      ]);
    // define your POST parameters (replace with your own values)
    $params = array(
      "access_token" => $token,
      "message" => $message,
      "link" => "http://www.mywebsite.com",
      "picture" => $filename
    );
    // post to Facebook
    try {
        $post = $fb->post('/MyPage/feed', $params);
        $post = $post->getGraphNode()->asArray();
        echo 'Successfully posted to Facebook';
    } catch(Exception $e) { echo $e->getMessage(); }
}
```

This script runs just fine except that I don't want to link the posted image to any site. I just need to post it as an unlinked image. But when I remove the following line from the function, Facebook refused the call saying I must define a link for an image post:

```
"link" => "http://www.mywebsite.com",
```

Is there any way to accomplish what I want to? There must be because I regularly post images to my page manually without having to link it to anything.

Comment: You need to upload the image instead. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/photos